# Returning both HTML and data (metadata?) from a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an app that will automatically populate a bracket based off of some data.

Currently I have a React component which displays the matchup between two teams. This component could calculate the predicted winner of the match, however I need to access that predicted winner elsewhere in my app.

So my component is very simple right now.

```
export const BracketMatchup = ({ highseed, lowseed, round }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={style.bracketMatchup}
      style={{ height: `calc(75px * ${round})` }}
    >
      <div className={style.highSeed}>{highseed?.name}</div>
      <div className={style.lowSeed}>{lowseed?.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The component takes a couple of seeds and just displays the information.

Pulling the app together I am stacking multiple instances of the `BracketMatchup` component.

```
    <div className={styles.bracket}>
      <div className={styles.bracketColumn}>
        <BracketMatchup
          highseed={getTeam("Kansas")}
          lowseed={getTeam("ISU")}
          round={1}
          id="1"
        />
        <BracketMatchup
          highseed={getTeam("TCU")}
          lowseed={getTeam("BYU")}
          round={1}
          id="2"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        className={styles.bracketColumn}
        style={{ marginTop: "calc(75px / 2)" }}
      >
        <BracketMatchup round={2} id="3"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now the problem I am having is that my last `BracketMatchup` component should use the projected winners from the previous two components. Ideally the `BracketMatchup` with `id=3` would take the winners from `BracketMatchup` with `id=1` and `id=2` however I am not sure how to return that data from the `BracketMatchup`

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/happy-ben-7h7c2l?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A25%2C39)

Comment: Hi! Necessary permission hasn't been granted for the code sandbox. Please check that out!

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a state management solution.  React has a native one called Context,  I like a library called Mobx, Redux is also very popular.

Comment: Hey @BryanDellinger,   context could work however I need around fifty instances of my `BracketMatchup` component so I would need a context value to manage each one.